# Why my LSTM model always start a prediction with a peak?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I want to find out why my LSTM NN always starts the forecast with a peak.

This is my model:
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5utX2.png)

And those are some Predictions:[Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dtW3.png)

If you check the red line always starts with a peak, can someone explain to me why?